# Can we select the table data without using select statement

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql

Is it possible to select the data using indexes without using select statement...

Comment: why would you need that? that is what `select` *is* for. Even your question is a contradiction: "select data without `select`"

Comment: Not with MySQL, no. @Barranka: PostgreSQL allows an abbreviated syntax where typing `table foobar` is equivalent to `select * from foobar`.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, you can not, you have to use it anyway. You can use stored procedure and call them from asp.net but `stored procedure` would have `select statement` to get data from tables.

Comment: Just for some fun, technically yes you can. You can issue a `mysqldump` and have data without a `SELECT` statement, not convenient or usable for many practical purposes but as a fun fact yeah you can :)